# How do i add a page to a web template in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a basic web template using the following post and added a custom list to it, this works fine. http://sebastiantegel.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/webtemplates-is-the-way-to-go/

I now want to add a screen/page to the web template which will show this list and also 2 visual web parts, the nav bars on the left should link to the page (i know how to do this part).

I am a new sharepoint developer.

I need to add a page to the web template which will show a list and also 2 custom visual web parts.

How do i do this in visual studio (it has to be done in visual studio)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of pages you can use in SharePoint.
The first one is called an application page. These are good for Administration type functions as well as pages you might want to expose for every site on your farm. They are easy to set up but be aware that they cannot be modified in SharePoint designer and they can't be used in a sandbox solution

[How to: Create an Application Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231578.aspx)

The second way is to upload the page to a library like the page library or other document library.

[How to: Include Files by Using a Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231524.aspx)

Application pages live on the hard drive. Pages uploaded with a module will live in the content database.

Good luck